# R how to pass a (potentially) missing argument?

Tags: r

I have in R a low level function that uses the missing() construct, and would like to use a high-level/wrapper that passes some arguments to it.

The problem is that even if the user does not provide the argument at the high-level, low-level function considers it is given, see:

```
## low level:
foo_low <- function(x, argA, argB){
 if(+missing(argA)) warning("argA was given")
 if(+missing(argB)) warning("argB was given")
 x+1
}
## wrapper/high level:
foo_high <- function(x, argA, argB){
  foo_low(x=x, argA=argA, argB=argB)
} 

## issue: low level will considere non missing even if missing at high level:
foo_high(2)
[1] 3
Warning :
1: In foo_low(x = x, argA = argA, argB = argB) : argA was given
2: In foo_low(x = x, argA = argA, argB = argB) : argB was given
```

How can I solve this elegantly? I could check inside the high-level function if called or not, and then do separate calls, but not very elegant. I could also use the ..., but not practical in my case. Any other suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: This is purely an `R` question and, as such, it should be migrated to StackOverflow. Since you've already assigned `r` tag, the question should get the proper attention there.

Comment: Sorry about this! How can I then do the migration to StackOverflow?

Comment: No problem at all. I've already flagged this question for migration to SO, so CV moderators will help with that. I will try to answer the question later, if I'll recall how I've used `missing()` (no promises, though :-). Can't focus at the moment - it's kind of late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `+` with `!` (logical *not*) in `foo_low` since you want to test whether the argument is **not** missing.

```
foo_low <- function(x, argA, argB){
  if(!missing(argA)) warning("argA was given")
  if(!missing(argB)) warning("argB was given")
  x+1
}

foo_high(2)
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Oh wow, was just a mistake of mine! So it is indeed working as expected, great! Thanks!