# How to pass down a missing argument in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function that internally calls another function that can have missing arguments. If I do not define a default `NULL` value for the argument in the high-level function the missing argument is correctly passed down. However, in the function documentation, I would like to explicitly indicate that the argument is optional by assigning a default `NULL` value to it.

In the following MWE, how could I make `high.foo2()` work more like `high.foo1()`?

```
low.foo <-  function(y = NULL) if(missing(y)) cat ('y is missing') else print(y)

high.foo1 <-  function(y) low.foo(y = y)
high.foo1()
# > y is missing

high.foo2 <-  function(y = NULL) low.foo(y = y)
high.foo2()
# > NULL
```

PD1. Not a duplicate of [R how to pass a (potentially) missing argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875389/r-how-to-pass-a-potentially-missing-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option to capture the argument and check if it is `"NULL"`

```
high.foo2 <-  function(y = NULL) {
  if(deparse(substitute(y)) == "NULL") low.foo() else low.foo(y = y)

}
```

-testing

```
high.foo2()
y is missing
```

---

Or may use `is.null`

```
high.foo2 <-  function(y = NULL) {
  if(is.null(substitute(y))) low.foo() else low.foo(y = y)

}
high.foo2()
y is missing
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed helpful, thank you. However, I have several arguments sharing this situation and think this can get kind of difficult to deal with in this way... Do you have any idea on how to generalize your solution? D:

Comment: @Crparedes if you have several arguments, then use `as.list(match.call())` and then check which of them is NULL